# PHP and JavaScript/Jquery returning different timestamp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I use this `new Date.getTime()` to get `current timestamp` in `jquery`. It gave me value `1380796448330`

But when I checked with `PHP time()` function it gave me :`1380796567`

Why is there a difference in length of both values?

Comment: What about [looking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) at the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)?

Comment: and here come downvoters..thanks..

Comment: Considering that the tooltip for the downvote button begins with "This question does not show any research effort", I don't believe you have grounds to complain. Not to mention complain about *earning less* rep which the 5/1 weight ratio ensures.

Comment: I am not complaining..but there is an another line in tooltip which says "not useful", i guess its not that useless ;) no grudges though :) and rep is not the thing i use SO for :)

Comment: Actually this is a common question that people are tend to ask frequently so I assume it could be useful for others as well if they google and find it here.

Comment: Js use client time and php use server time.

Comment: Obviously. Except the server-side JavaScript applications.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JavaScript [`Date.getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime#Description) method returns the time since start of Unix Epoch in milliseconds and PHP [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function returns it in seconds.

So if you want to use the timestamp from client-side in PHP you should divide it by thousand.
And vice versa if you want to use the timestamp retrieved in PHP at the client side (e.g. to pass it into the `Date` constructor) you should multiply it to thousand.

Comment: Also, I like to add JQuery/Javascript use timestamp based on the Browser, where as PHP use Timestamp of Server, so if server is different from client machine than their time might be different.

Answer (score 1):

Hi difference is mentioned here take look (Counted Timestamp blog) and will help u ...
http://cw.tactileint.com/++Dates_and_Times/JavaScript,PHP